# Where an I find performance insight metrics `db.SQL.total_query_time.avg` in CloudWatch?

Tags: r, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

There is a useful metrics from AWS RDS Performance Insight called `db.SQL.total_query_time.avg` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_PerfInsights_Counters.html#USER_PerfInsights_Counters.Aurora_PostgreSQL)

I would like to setup alarm for it. However I cannot find it anywhere in Cloudwatch. Does any one know if it exists in Cloudwatch?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS Performance Insights metrics are not shown on AWS CloudWatch Metrics Dashboard, but you can query RDS Performance Insights metrics using APIs, you could create custom AWS Lambda function to query those metrics and trigger an alert using AWS SNS. Below you can find links to access metrics using AWS SDK and CLI APIs.

**AWS CLI**
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/pi.html#PI.Client.get_resource_metrics

**AWS SDK**
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/pi/get-resource-metrics.html